# How to find the header section no. of the cell in uitableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have create uitableview which has section and cell like drop down. Each cell has created using collectionview.

For example, when I tap the "color" section. [Here I am storing the section number.] UICollectionView cell is expand. I can able to check and uncheck those cells.

```
- (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
     findSection = gestureRecognizer.view.tag;
  }
```

[image]

My Problem is, If all of the section is ON, when I tap cell directly to any of the section, the last section which I have tapped, those cells are changed. Not the current section of the cell which I have tapped.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];

    nonChecked = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check"];
    checked = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_active"];

    checkbox = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 9, 11, 11)];
    checkbox.tag = indexPath.row+100;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myChecked:)];
    tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    checkbox.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [checkbox addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:checkbox];

    NSIndexPath * myIndexPath =  [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+100 inSection:findSection];

    NSString * result = [[SingletonClass shareSingleton].resultOfFilter member:myIndexPath];

    if(result != nil)
        NSLog(@"Already checked!");
    else
        NSLog(@"Its unchecked!");

    if([self.checkedIndexPaths member:myIndexPath]{
        checkbox.image = checked;
    }
    else{
        checkbox.image = nonChecked;
    }

    UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 5, 70, 20)];
    label.text = [[[sectionContentDict valueForKey:[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:[(AFIndexedCollectionView *)collectionView indexPath].section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    label.textColor = WhiteColor;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Show the code that you have written inside collectionView method  `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, also show the code that is used to check and uncheck the cell.

Comment: just add a button on section header with width and height equal to secrionheader and then detect its action

Comment: 0 section and 1 section are ON. How can find which section of the cell I am tapping ?

Comment: the problem is in this line `NSIndexPath * myIndexPath =  [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+100 inSection:findSection];`, with `findSection`, i think you have set findsection = last on section.

Comment: @NDoc  yes. That is my problem. I think You understood. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: @NDoc I'm not able to get the table section no. which i have tapped inside uicollectionviewcell. Getting last on section value always.. how can i get?

Comment: Why are you using collectionView inside tableViewCell, instead of collectionView with section?

Comment: @NDoc ya. I think your way is better. But I have started with UITableViewCell. Then I have added UICollectionView instead in its contentView. so is there anyway to solve this or have to change to collectionview? .